# Multiple record submit without nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm sure I'm over thinking this problem, but I can't seem figure out how to simply create and submit multiple records at once. I have a User model and a Prediction model. User has_many predictions, and a Prediction belongs_to a user. I've nested my routes like so

```
:resources users do 
    :resources predictions
end
```

when I visit users/1/predictions/new, I need to create 6 Prediction records, and submit them at once to the db.

In my Predictions controller:

```
before_filter :load_user

def new
  3.times { @user.predictions.build }
end

def create
  @prediction = @user.predictions.new(params[:prediction])
  if @prediction.save
    redirect_to @user, :notice => 'Prediction added'
  else
    redirect_to @user, :notice => 'Unable to add'
  end
end

def destroy
  @prediction = @user.prediction.find(params[:id])
  @prediction.destroy
  redirect_to @user, :notice => "Prediction deleted"
end

private

def load_user
  @user = current_user
end
```

And in my Prediction new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @user.predictions.new]) do |f| %>
<div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :position %>
    <%= f.text_field :position %>
</div>
<div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :athlete_id, 'Athlete'%>
    <%= f.collection_select(:athlete_id, Athlete.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select an athlete' )%>
</div>
<div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :race_id, 'Race'%>
    <%= f.collection_select(:race_id, Race.upcoming, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select a race' )%>
</div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

This shows and submits only one record instead of 3. I thought I might have to use :accepts_nested_attributes_for, however I don't need to create and update User models at the same time. Existing Users will be creating predictions 3 records at a time for several Races, as this is a fantasy sports app.

Comment: Why don't you want to use nested forms?  It seems like they would fit your problem perfectly.

Comment: I can definitely use them, I guess I didn't understand the concept properly. I thought nested attributes were only relevant when you were create or edit two models at once. In my case, a User already exists, and I just need to create 3 predictions for that user and submit them together.

Comment: ActiveRecord should not update the existing user record unless you make changes to it, so I think it's perfectly acceptable to use nested forms in your case.  Your questions and concerns about the existing user record were very astute. +1 for good thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the very first item, the nested route may not be the approach you are looking for.  That may tie you down to 1 new model prediction record on the form.

You do indeed want `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model.  With that set use a form_for (and simple_form_for if possible, using the [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem).  Then with code like
form_for @user do |f|
use f.fields_for :prediction

The user controller save methods will also validate and save the nested records automatically.

As you may know Ryan Bates has great [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for this.